# How can I influence the spacing of mathematical functions by an own macro?

Tags: spacing, macros, math-operators

I would like to get a macro `\of` to define a function with an optional macro `\at` to define its restriction. 
The reason is, that I don't like the spacing for functions (as there is no spacing) and I would like to automate that. The idea is, to set functions like `f \of x` or `f\of x` which would be quick and handy. But I am not sure, if that is doable for syntax reasons. I think, something like `\func{f}{x}` would be much easier to provide, but that would be too much typing and quite a lot of change for already existing formulae.

However, the reasons for this macro are the following properties which I would like to achieve. In future I want to expand this to all kind of derivatives or alike (total, partial, normal, increment, infinite element...).

Here is the list:

- Always set argument (value behind `\of` in ()
- Recognize x, (x), and {x} as argument
- always set half space in front of the function when it is set behind a letter, number or bracket
- set half space behind the function, if followed by a (
- allow powers to the function and to the argument and set it properly
- allow nested functions
- allow `\at`-notation with three optional formats (this will get interesting later on for the derivatives...)

And here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}f \of x=x^2\end{verbatim}
$f(x)=x^2$
\begin{verbatim}f \of (x+y)=x+y\end{verbatim}
$f(x+y)=x+y$
\begin{verbatim}f \of (x+y)x+y\end{verbatim}
$f(x+y)x+y$
\begin{verbatim}f \of (x+y)(x+y)(x+y)\end{verbatim}
$f(x+y)\,(x+y)(x+y)$
\begin{verbatim}xf \of xx\end{verbatim}
$x\,f(x)x$
\begin{verbatim}zf \of xg \of yz\end{verbatim}
$z\,f(x)\,g(y)z$
\begin{verbatim}f^2 \of x\end{verbatim}
$f^2(x) \vee f(x)^2 \vee (f(x))^2 \quad \text{don't know which one is correct}$
\begin{verbatim}f \of x^2\end{verbatim}
$f(x^2)$
\begin{verbatim}f \of g \of x\end{verbatim}
$f(g(x))$
\begin{verbatim}\frac{a}{b}f\of x\end{verbatim}
$\dfrac{a}{b}f(x)$
\begin{verbatim}(a+b)f\of x\end{verbatim}
$(a+b)\,f(x)$
\begin{verbatim}\setFunctionAtBar \end{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}f \of x \at a\end{verbatim}
$f(x)|_{x=a}$
\begin{verbatim}\setFunctionAtBracket\end{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}f \of x \at {a+b}\end{verbatim}
$(f(x))_{x=(a+b)}$
\begin{verbatim}\setFunctionAtInline\end{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}f \of x \at (a+b)\end{verbatim}
$f(a+b)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex goes to a lot of effort to have a consistent syntax `\frac{a}{b}` not `a \over b`, `\hspace{2in}` not `\hskip 2in` etc :(

Comment: hmmm, I will think of an other notation, which would be easy. But is there something around, doing the other stuff? I got the feeling, there has to be something, but I can't find it.

Comment: Something like `$(a+b)\,f(x)$` or `(f(x))_{}`, ie. inserting things way before `\of` is almost impossible without making things active or pre-processing the whole content. The `\of` doesn't know what came before it. (You can however put `\mathinner{(a+b)}` which, I believe, includes spacing around it.) Otherwise this is probably doable with a few `ifnextchar`s, but do you really want that (see David's comment)? `xparse` can probably help with a `\func` macro.

Comment: I already gathered that the syntax is the major problem. But your point about pre-processing is very interesting. I will have a look on xparse when CTAN is on again.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from syntax it seems main issue is spacing before a function term. TeX will add space there automatically if it knows it is a function. `\log` `\sin` etc are `\mathop` atoms and get space, but `f` is a mathord so does not. If you declare a one-letter  math operator though, it gets the space that I think you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
$zf(x)$

$z\mathop{{}f}(x)$

\end{document}
```